# Function and difference between $() and ${} in Makefile

Tags: makefile

In makefile, `${CC} -o myfile myfile.c` and `$(CC) -o myfile myfile.c` both work fine even without definition of CC.
My question is:

1. How to use `$(..)` and `${..}`?

- Are they just convert the string in `{}` or `()` to lowercase if that string is not defined?
- Why does `$${dir}` need two `$$` in
  `for dir in ${DIR}; do (cd $${dir}; ${MAKE}); done`

2. Is there any differences between `${}` and `$()`?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is no difference between `()` and `{}` for Make.

If you use `$$` in a recipe, then `$` is "escaped" and passed to the shell.  The shell may then make a difference between `$()` or `${}`.  But that is entirely up to the shell, and has nothing to do with Make or makefiles.

In the recipe command that you quote

```
for dir in ${DIR}; do (cd $${dir}; ${MAKE}); done
```

Make does this:

- substitutes the value of `DIR`, for `${DIR}`, and that could just as well have been `$(DIR)`
- replaces `$$` with `$` ("escaping", so that `$` could be passed to the shell)
- substitutes the value of `MAKE` for `${MAKE}`, again this could have been `$(MAKE)`.  The value of `MAKE` is automatically setup by Make, to the make executable that is being used.
- passes the resulting string to shell for execution - the shell then interprets the one remaining `${}` the way it wants.

`CC`, similarly to `MAKE` is one of those variables that are by default pre-defined by Make, that's why it "works" even if you don't set it yourself.

By the way, a better way to write this recipe for "target" is

```
.PHONY: $(DIR)
target: $(DIR)
$(DIR):
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

Please consult the manual for explanation of things that are unclear.

Comment: This documentation (https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reference.html#Reference) confirms that there is no difference between `$(foo)` and `${foo}`; either is a valid reference to the variable `foo`.

Answer (score -4):

```
$(CC) - is evaluate ; this can be a command

Vs

${CC} - is dereference; just get value of a variable
```

Comment: Downvoted because this is for shell, not for Makefile.  See accepted answer